# Why floating point relative accuracy is needed?

Tags: convergence-divergence, matlab, floating-point

In checking convergence of an iterative method, I have found that MATLAB uses the following code:`dw = max(max(abs(W-Wnew) / (sqrt(eps)+max(max(abs(Wnew))))));`

Here, W is old parameter, Wnew is updated parameter. While I understand the above code is trying to find relative change, I fail to find the reason why sqrt(eps) (eps is called [Floating Point Relative Accuracy](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), eps=2^-52) is being added. So, if anyone can shed some light on this, I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably to have a formula that works in the case `Wnew = 0.0` and other small numbers.

Comment: It probably doesn't want to divide by 0.

Comment: hmm, I guessed so but why square rooting it?